# Rehosting install4j ( 4.2.8 ) License to another server

Tags: install4j

I have tried searching through internet about my query and also tried finding here on this site . But no luck .

Sorry , we are very much new to install4j but have been asked to perform some task .

Our organization has install4j floating license (purchased one) . We have one CentOS  Linux machine  "ABC"  serving as License Server for this install4j .

Now , we plan to shutdown this machine "ABC" and would like to have another RHEL  Linux  machine "XYZ"  serving as License Server for our  install4j .

Please note , version of our install4j is 4.2.8 .

Can you please send us the instructions for this activity ?

Thanks,
Vishal Chugh

Answer (score 0):

It works like this:

- Install the license server on the new machine
- Transfer the file license.txt from the old license server to the new license server
- Shut down the old license server
- Start the new license server